# How can I count the number of numbers in a string

Tags: python, string, tokenize

I want to count the number of numbers in s string.

In this string:

> "2019 was a great year for 10 fortunate people in ages 20 to 60."

The result should be 4 (2019, 10, 20, 60)
Thanks

Comment: Use a regular expression to match numbers, then count the number of matches in `re.findall()`.

Comment: Short answer: use a regex

Comment: I'd split the string between spaces, perform `int()` on each word and see how many times it does not fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For counting integers only, you can use a simple [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```py
import re
s = '2019 was a great year for 10 fortunate people in ages 20 to 60.'
n = len(re.findall(r'\d+', s))  # 4
```

Here `'\d+'` means "one or more decimal characters in a row".

Note that `re.findall` produces a `list` of the results. If you only care about the number of elements (`n`), this is wasteful for input strings containing very many numbers. Instead, make use of an iterator approach, e.g.

```py
import re
s = '2019 was a great year for 10 fortunate people in ages 20 to 60.'
n = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\d+', s))  # 4
```

#### Incorporating floats

Let's say that you allow `float`s like `1.2` and `3e-4` etc. as well. The corresponding regular expression is now much more complicated, and an easier solution would be to just loop over all "words" in the string and check if they can be interpreted as a number:

```py
def is_number(num):
    try:
        float(num)
    except:
        return False
    return True

s = '2019 was a great year for 10 fortunate people in ages 20 to 60.'
n = sum(1 for num in s.split() if is_number(num))  # 4
```

Answer (score 2):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) is a pretty simple way to deal with this:

```
import re

s = "2019 was a great year for 10 fortunate people in ages 20 to 60."

# find all groups of digits
re.findall(r'\d+', s)
# ['2019', '10', '20', '60']
```

This assumes the numbers are not floats with decimal points or other non-integer things.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string into tokens using `s.split(' ')` and iterate over each and use a regex like `\d+` to test that each character is a digit, and accumulate good test responses in an int.